# How to change hdfs block size in pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, apache-spark-1.6

I use pySpark to write parquet file. I would like to change the hdfs block size of that file. I set the block size like this and it doesn't work:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dfs.block.size", "128m")
```

Does this have to be set before starting the pySpark job? If so, how to do it.

Comment: Hi, if any of below answers has solved your problem please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) the best answer or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Comment: I am not sure you can change it, this is how the file is written in the HDFS. Spark will allocate a task per file partition (kind of mapper). That why lot of people recommend to have block of 256m for Spark.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting it through `sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()` with **SparkContext**

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext 
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("yarn")) 
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dfs.block.size", "128m")
txt = sc.parallelize(("Hello", "world", "!"))
txt.saveAsTextFile("hdfs/output/path") #saving output with 128MB block size
```

in Scala:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("dfs.block.size", "128m")
```

Comment: It is not working. I am using pyspark version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue, but I figured out the issue. It needs a number not "128m". Therefore this should work (worked for me at least!):

```
block_size = str(1024 * 1024 * 128)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dfs.block.size", block_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set blockSize of files that spark write:

```
myDataFrame.write.option("parquet.block.size", 256 * 1024 * 1024).parquet(destinationPath)
```