# Reading data using Structured Streaming in Pyspark and wants to write data with file size of 100MB

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark

hope you all are fine.
I'm reading files from a directory using structured streaming

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("RowNo", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceNo", StringType()),
    StructField("StockCode", StringType()),
    StructField("Description", StringType()),
    StructField("Quantity", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceDate", StringType()),
    StructField("UnitPrice", StringType()),
    StructField("CustomerId", StringType()),
    StructField("Country", StringType()),
    StructField("InvoiceTimestamp", StringType())
])

data = spark.readStream.format("orc").schema(schema).option("header", "true").option("path", "<path_here>").load()
```

After applying some transformations, I like to save the output files with size of 100MB.

Comment: You are reading a file and writing as file. Why spark structured streaming? Does it act like a file watcher?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the default HDFS blocksize.

```
block_size = str(1024 * 1024 * 100)

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("dfs.block.size", block_size)
```

Reference: [How to change hdfs block size in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954825/how-to-change-hdfs-block-size-in-pyspark)

Comment: It is not working for me, It is creating 112MB of files

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb Sorry mate, I'll dig some more